# Find object by css class from code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a table with subtables. I would like to get all the indexs of the rows by a css value.
Is this possible from the code behind?

In this example I would like to know witch row number childRow has.

```
<table id="ctl00_contentHolder_tbl_main" class="tablesorter tablesorter-default" border="1" style="background-color:White;border-style:Solid;" rules="all">
<thead>
<tbody>
<tr class="grey">
<tr class="grey">
<tr class="grey">
<tr class="childRow">
<tr class="grey">
<tr class="grey">
```

Comment: CSS is just for styling. if you want to do any data related things, you have to use JavaScript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only work in code-behind with controls that have `runat="server" ID="xxx"` attributes. If a control has these attributes you can reference them and retrieve their attributes (including CSS class name). If not then the HTML code is treated as text by ASP.NET engine and not as elements/controls.